# Pushing folder's contents into a folder inside a repository?

Tags: github

Let's say a have a repository named `the-odin-project`, and inside this repository I have a folder called `my-first-rails-app`.

Now, in my computer, I have a folder called `local-my-first-rails-app` which contains all the files I need.

I am trying this:

```
git remote add origin <SSH URL from above>
git push -u origin master
```

However, it pushes all the files inside the folder into the repository.

How can I push all those files inside the `local-my-first-rails-app` (the folder in my comptuer) folder into the folder `my-first-rails-app`, which is inside the repository `the-odin-project`?

Comment: Does `git add <path_to_local-my-first-rails-app>` before committing and pushing not work?

Comment: @SunnyPatel hey, just tried; it gave this error: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: Then you need to first clone/fork the repository locally before you copy over the `local-my-first-rails-app` folder, and then perform as my first comment suggests.

Comment: @SunnyPatel it worked! thank you so much!